# How to embed Linkedln posts in angular application

Tags: angular, embed, media, timeline

How to embed Linkedln posts in angular application

How to embed Linkedln posts in angular application

Comment: Please read what kind of questions you can ask on StackOverflow here https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask In short: ask about specific problems instead of asking for whole guide.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.